# How to merge array of objects in one object, including inner objects - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have the following array of objects:

```
var list = [
  { a: 1, 
    b: { c: 'x', k: []}
  },
  { a: 1,
    b: {c: 'x', d: 8}
  }
];
```

I want them to be merged into one "generic" object, for this example, it would be:

```
{a: 1, b: {c: 'x', d:'8', k[]}}
```

As you can see, all nested objects are merged too. But I can't gain it. If I use Object.assign it creates new nested objects if they are different, that is duplicates them:

```
var res = Object.assign({}, ...list);
// res: {
    a: 1, 
    b: {c: 'x', k: []},
    b: {c: 'x', d: 8}
}
```

Comment: How about using a loop similar to this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following using the `reduce` method:

```js
var list = [{
  a: 1,
  b: {
    a: 4,
    k: 3
  }
}, {
  a: 1,
  s: 11,
  b: {
    ab: 4,
    d: 8
  }
}]

var result = list.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  var obj = { ...item
  }
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item) {
    if (acc[item]) { //if a property with the the key, 'item' already exists, then append to that
      Object.assign(acc[item], obj[item]);
    } else { // else add the key-value pair to the accumulator object.
      acc[item] = obj[item];
    }
  })
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This code actually has a bug. As soon as a nested object starts from different field it stops working: [
      {a: 1, 
       b: {a: 4, k: 3}
      },
      {a: 1,
       s:11,
      b: {ab: 4, d: 8}
      }
]

Comment: My mistake. Just edited the code. Please see if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

[Deep merging](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-deep-merge) is not simple to do yourself, That blog uses [deep merge](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/deepmerge).

If you don't have webpack or nodejs you can use deepmerge like so:

```js
// see https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b5ac963fb791d1298e7f396236383bc955f916c1/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L21-L25
var canUseSymbol = typeof Symbol === 'function' && Symbol.for
var REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE = canUseSymbol ? Symbol.for('react.element') : 0xeac7

function isReactElement(value) {
 return value.$$typeof === REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE
}

function isNonNullObject(value) {
 return !!value && typeof value === 'object'
}

function isSpecial(value) {
 var stringValue = Object.prototype.toString.call(value)

 return stringValue === '[object RegExp]'
  || stringValue === '[object Date]'
  || isReactElement(value)
}

function defaultIsMergeableObject(value) {
 return isNonNullObject(value)
  && !isSpecial(value)
}



function emptyTarget(val) {
 return Array.isArray(val) ? [] : {}
}

function cloneUnlessOtherwiseSpecified(value, options) {
 return (options.clone !== false && options.isMergeableObject(value))
  ? deepmerge(emptyTarget(value), value, options)
  : value
}

function defaultArrayMerge(target, source, options) {
 return target.concat(source).map(function(element) {
  return cloneUnlessOtherwiseSpecified(element, options)
 })
}

function mergeObject(target, source, options) {
 var destination = {}
 if (options.isMergeableObject(target)) {
  Object.keys(target).forEach(function(key) {
   destination[key] = cloneUnlessOtherwiseSpecified(target[key], options)
  })
 }
 Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
  if (!options.isMergeableObject(source[key]) || !target[key]) {
   destination[key] = cloneUnlessOtherwiseSpecified(source[key], options)
  } else {
   destination[key] = deepmerge(target[key], source[key], options)
  }
 })
 return destination
}

function deepmerge(target, source, options) {
 options = options || {}
 options.arrayMerge = options.arrayMerge || defaultArrayMerge
 options.isMergeableObject = options.isMergeableObject || defaultIsMergeableObject

 var sourceIsArray = Array.isArray(source)
 var targetIsArray = Array.isArray(target)
 var sourceAndTargetTypesMatch = sourceIsArray === targetIsArray

 if (!sourceAndTargetTypesMatch) {
  return cloneUnlessOtherwiseSpecified(source, options)
 } else if (sourceIsArray) {
  return options.arrayMerge(target, source, options)
 } else {
  return mergeObject(target, source, options)
 }
}

deepmerge.all = function deepmergeAll(array, options) {
 if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
  throw new Error('first argument should be an array')
 }

 return array.reduce(function(prev, next) {
  return deepmerge(prev, next, options)
 }, {})
}
var list = [{
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 'x',
    //merging 1,2 and 1,3 results in [1,2,1,3] you can change that in defaultArrayMerge
    k: [1,2]
  }
},
{
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 'x',
    k: [1,3],
    d: 8
  }
}];

console.log(
  deepmerge.all(list)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `reduce` method. Remove the first element from the original list , that object will be the base method.

```js
var list = [{
    a: 1,
    b: {
      c: 'x',
      k: []
    }
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: {
      c: 'x',
      d: 8
    }
  }
];
// Remove the first element from the array. The first element will be
// the base object
// slice will return a new array without the first object
// apply reduce on this list
let _temp = list.slice(1);
let x = _temp.reduce(function(acc,curr,currIndex){
    for(let keys in curr){
      // checking if the base object have the same key as of current object
      if(acc.hasOwnProperty(keys)){
          // if base object and current object has the key then 
         // check if the type is an object
         if(typeof curr[keys] ==='object'){
          // now get the key from both the object 
          // & check which one is missong. Add that key and value to the 
          // base object
           let keysFromACC = Object.keys(acc[keys]);
          let keysFromCURR = Object.keys(curr[keys]);
          keysFromCURR.forEach(function(item){
           if(keysFromACC.indexOf(item) ===-1){
              acc[keys][item] = curr[keys][item]
           }
          })
         }
      }
      else{
       // if the base object does not have key which current object
       // has then add the key to base object
       acc[keys]= curr[keys]
      }
    
    }
    return acc;

},list[0]);


console.log(x)
```

Comment: Note that this moves the [problem of deep merging](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-deep-merge) only one level deeper and works with the data provided but not for 3rd level nested objects like `list[x].b.k`.